# Reading multiple files in multithreaded mode

Tags: java, multithreading

I have `ArrayList`. It contains about 20,000 file path elements.

```
private List<Path> listOfPaths = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to read the contents of files on these paths in multithreaded mode.
The problem is that this code runs quite slowly. How can I select several threads so that each of them reads the file and writes it to the `dto`? How to solve the problem of one thread starting to process a file so that the other thread does not do the same with the same file?

Comment: The bottleneck here is most likely your disk. Using several threads will not help in this case.

Comment: Several ways to go about this. You can pre-divide the work each thread has to do, so that no two threads have the same files to process. Or just have a queue that every thread currently idle can refer to to get the next to be processed file from. Btw, depending on what you're doing, this will be IO bound, so multiple threads will not make your algorithm any faster.

Comment: Henry that claim would depend highly of the file size, the driver and actual disk used. Typically with traditional disks, processing small files goes slowly but many read can be performed in parallel, in particular disk designed for servers and alike. The actual performance would depend a lot of the actual file size, the read operation performed, the disk driver and the technology behind.

Comment: In your example the paramsList object can't be sately shared among threads and on top of that you don't wait for the computation to be finished. (like with taking the future returned by submit and calling get on it and using for example a Vector instead of an ArrayList).

Answer (score 1):

I created ioPool to not to block common-pool(which is used by default on parallel stream operations) with io operations. Normally it is advised if you are doing io operations you can create `core-count* 2` threads, but it is really io limited as others mentioned.

You can do this like below. This won't process your file list in order.

```
 ForkJoinPool ioPool = new ForkJoinPool(8);
 ForkJoinTask<?> tasks = ioPool.submit(
              () -> pathList.parallelStream().forEach(//your code here);
 tasks.get(); // this blocks until all threads finishes in the pool
```

Comment: I try this. I updated the question. But, At the end in `paramsList` I have 0 elements, while using a loop I have 20,000 elements in it.

Comment: @All_Safe You have to wait pool to finish, I add the code in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can likely split the work in smaller chunks, each thread processing a portion of all the files. Each thread would have his own sub list of data to processed and list of processed data to avoid any risk of trying to read/write the same data at the same time. When all the thread have finished, you would colect the results.

Actually you can let java 8 parallel stream do the hard work of splitting/mergin etc for you.

Using standard streams not using multiple threads:

```
List<ParamsDTO> paramsList = listOfPaths.stream().map(p -> readFile(p)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using parallel streams for improved performance:

```
List<ParamsDTO> paramsList = listOfPaths.parallelStream().map(p -> readFile(p)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where you have defined the function readFile as something like:

```
public ParamDTO readFile(Path p) {
    ParamsDTO params = new ParamsDTO();
    params.setParams(Files.readAllBytes(path));
    return params;
}
```

You'll likely want to go beyond that in the long run, controlling the level of parallelism depending of the type of disk and to get more control, go with Java 5 executors for managing the thread pool characteristics and plain runable or futures for tasks to run.